# Pocket Calculators- Obsolete?

Tags: soft-question, calculator

*I hope this fits into "software that mathematicians use" within the acceptable topics for this site.*

Are there still any instances where pocket calculators prove useful to professional mathematicians or professionals working in mathematical fields? If so, what are some examples and what are the most sought-after models?

Comment: In my experience, if a mathematician relies on some simple arithmetic for a one-time computation, then they may have a pocket calculator. However, usually no particular model is sought-after. For the post part it is just whatever is cheapest.

Comment: Computers are the modern day pocket calculators and they are used alot in many fields.

Comment: For research level math a calculator isn't particularly helpful. Even the calculators that do symbolic algebra are so inferior to a computer (or actually even a cell phone) as to not be worth the money. As Winther says computers are used extensively By many (but not all) mathematicians.